# Unable to Run Spring Form based application(By using MVC architecture)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring.I have made an application named "BookWorkshop" using spring-3.1 by following MVC architecture.but as soon as I'm hitting the 
`url:http://localhost:8087/BookWorkshop`  I'm getting the error as follows:

**org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class' for property 'commandClass'**.

I'm attaching my code herewith::

Spring servlet class:bookdispatcher-servlet.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xs">

  <bean name="/welcome_book.html" class="com.edifixio.controller.UserBookController"/>

  <bean name="/new_book.html" class="com.edifixio.controller.StoreBookController">
      <property name="commandClass" value="com.edifixio.model.UserBook"/>
      <property name="formView" value="addnewbook"/>
      <property name="successView" value="/welcome_book.html"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="viewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
       p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"         
       p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
       p:suffix=".jsp"/>  
</beans>
```

Form controller class:::StoreBookController.java as follows

```
public class StoreBookController extends SimpleFormController {

   @Override
   protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
     UserBook book = new UserBook(0,"Enter Book Name", null, 0);
     return book;
   }

    @Override
    protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
      Map<Object, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
      PublisherManager manager = new PublisherManager();
      dataMap.put("publishierList", manager.getPublishierList());
      return dataMap;
   }

   @Override
  protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder  dataBinder) throws Exception {
    dataBinder.setDisallowedFields(new String[]{"publishier"});
    UserBook userBook = (UserBook) dataBinder.getTarget();
    PublisherManager manager = new PublisherManager();
    Long publishierid = null;
    try {
        publishierid = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("publishier"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    if (publishierid != null) {
        userBook.setPublisher(manager.getPublishierById(publishierid));
    }
  }

   @Override
   public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws ServletException {
     BookManager bookManager = new BookManager();
     bookManager.createBook((UserBook) command);
     return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
    }
 }
```

then my **formView** page named:::**addnewbook.jsp** as follows---

```
      <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
      <%@taglib prefix="sp" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
      <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>JSP Page</title>
     </head>
   <body>
      <h1>ADD BOOK</h1>
      <sp:form method="post">
           Publisher:<sp:select path="publisher"> 
               <sp:options items="${publisherList}" itemLabel="publishername" itemValue="publisherid"/>
          </sp:select>
           <br/><br/>
          Book Name:<sp:input path="bookname"/>
           <br/><br/>
          Price:<sp:input path="price"/>
           <br/><br/>
          <input type="submit" value="SAVE"/>
       </sp:form>
   </body>
</html>
```

finally successView controller class named:UserBookController.java as follows

```
public class UserBookController implements Controller {

  @Override
  public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws Exception {
     BookManager manager = new BookManager();
     ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("booklist");
     modelAndView.addObject("allbook", manager.createBookCollection());
     return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**successView** page named:**booklist.jsp** as follows:::

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>JSP Page</title>
   </head>
  <body>
      <h1>BOOK  WORKSHOP  APPLICATION</h1>
           <table style="border:2;color:graytext" >
           <th style="color: background;alignment-adjust: baseline">Book Name</th>
           <th style="color: background">Price</th>
           <th style="color: background">Publisher</th>
           <c:forEach items="${allbook}" var="b">
              <tr>
                  <td style="color:burlywood">${b.bookname}</td> 
                  <td style="color:burlywood">${b.price}</td>
                  <td style="color:burlywood">${b.publisher.publishername}</td>
              </tr>
           </c:forEach>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

finally **web.xml** file is here:::::::

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    /web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>/new_book.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>bookdispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>bookdispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <session-config>
      <session-timeout>
        30
      </session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   </web-app>
```

can anyone give any solution to this?????????????

Comment: try the Hello World tutorials from here http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: And please upgrade to a newer version of Spring. You really shouldn't be using `SimpleFormController`.

Comment: I have allready made one small application similar to mkyong "Helloworld" program and run that successfully.Now,I'm moving onto form based application and trying to make a form and submit its value so n so.That's where I faced this problem.So,please give me solution based on my problem. @ Evgeny

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<property name="commandClass">  
            <value>  
                com.edifixio.model.UserBook 
            </value>  
</property>
```

Comment: that is what I have written.

Comment: You specified value as an attribute of <property>. Try to specify it as an inner tag

Comment: no its not working getting same error as mentioned previously

Answer (score 0):

you can download a fully working spring mvc form based example from [here](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-processing.jsp) . You can then modify that example in whatever way you want.